# Merging of branches in Git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am new to git and merging of branches is a concept I can't understand. I am working on a project and client often asks to add some new feature on production. My approach is to first add that feature on dev branch then test it there, if it works fine I commit the changes and push them to upstream dev branch and then cherry pick that commit to `uat` and push to `uat` of upstream and then cherry pick that `uat` commit to `production` branch and deploy it.

My senior has told me not to do that because there might be some changes in `uat` which are not in production and cherry pick may lead to conflicts. He told me to first create a branch(myFeature lets call it) from production branch(I don't know if he meant production branch of origin or of upstream),make changes their and then if I wanna test those changes on dev I can merge that `myFeature` to `dev`.

I want to learn step by step how to create a new branch from production branch and then merge it to dev branch and ultimately raise a PR to merge that myFeature branch to production branch.
Thanks

Comment: Your senior gave the right suggestion. What they did not say, but implied is that after you have merged dev into your feature branch and tested it, you are expected to reset your branch to before the merge and then create the pull request. IOW, the merge is just temporary for testing, and does not enter the final product.

Comment: Please read this article - https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ - it will help you a lot.

Comment: By the way, it's rarely right to use *both* the github and bitbucket tags; in this case you probably don't need either one, but if you are asking about GitHub-specific items you'd use the [tag:github] tag, and if you're asking about Bitbucket-specific items you'd use the [tag:bitbucket] tag.

Comment: yead this article is helpful,also if i create a new branch on prod branch to add some new feature and if i merge that new branch to dev branch just to test if it is working fine,how do i unmerge from dev and remerge that feature branch to prod branch?

Comment: It's easiest to create a temporary branch from your feature branch, call it tmp, then merge dev into tmp, test, then switch back to your feature branch and remove tmp.

Comment: Do we need to commit our changes on feature branch before merging it with dev/sit branch.